# extending monolog.logger.class in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, monolog

I want to extend monolog logger in Symfony to add method like:

```
public function logException(\Exception $e)
{
    $this->error($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
}
```

I added new service trying to override logger

```
logger:
    class: ...\AppBundle\Service\MyLogger
```

or

```
MyLogger:
    class: Namespace\MyLogger
logger:
    alias: MyLogger
```

My code is working but PhpStorm cannot index `$this->get('logger')`

> logException($e) mark "logException" method as undefined.

The logger for PHPStorm still pointing to \Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger

What is the right way to extend `monolog.logger.class` and add custom logic?